# I have to set up ftp

Tags: asp.net

I have to first call `exe` that generate `.txt` file.
And then `FTP` to push that file .
And I have to do this in `.bat` file. It first call the `.exe` to generate file 
and then send that file through ftp.
`.exe` generate file in `d:/csst/zppr1.txt`. How to do this?

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) What difficulties did you encounter with your code that you would like to ask about? Without this information we cannot help you much.

Comment: I have only generated exe that generate file and my boss has given  credentials for ftp.

Comment: Alright, so now you might try searching about how to [`upload a file on FTP using C#`](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=upload+file+ftp+c%23). Then try to implement it. And if you encounter some problems do not hesitate to show your code here so that we can help you. I hope you realize that nobody is going to write the code for you on StackOverflow. That's not how this site is meant to be used.